# how to load huge dataframe in linear regression?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

i have a dataframe with more than 1 millions row and i need do a linear regression on this dataframe in python3. but my Ram is 8 GB and i can't load the dataframe completely and run linear regression on that.

my code is as follow:

```
def get_data():
    client = MongoClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=27017)
    database = client['database']
    collection = database['AI']
    query = {}
    
    return collection.find(query)

df = get_data()
xx = pd.DataFrame(df[0:100000])
xx = xx.iloc[:,2:]
xx.dropna(inplace = True)
X = np.array(xx.iloc[:,:-1])

y = np.array(xx['price']).reshape(-1, 1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
regr = LinearRegression()
 
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(regr.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: I can see you are trying to do cross validation. For seeing how accurate your model is, your might not need the full data frame. Can you specify at which step did you run out of memory?

Comment: xx = pd.DataFrame(df[0:100000]) as you can see i only import 100000 documents but i have more than 1 millions documents

Answer (score 0):

May not be possible for `LinearRegression`, but `SGDRegessor` has a method `partial_fit` to handle large datasets.

To quote : [here](https://partial_fit(X,%20y,%20sample_weight=None)%5Bsource%5D%20Perform%20one%20epoch%20of%20stochastic%20gradient%20descent%20on%20given%20samples.%20%20Internally,%20this%20method%20uses%20max_iter%20=%201.%20Therefore,%20it%20is%20not%20guaranteed%20that%20a%20minimum%20of%20the%20cost%20function%20is%20reached%20after%20calling%20it%20once.%20Matters%20such%20as%20objective%20convergence%20and%20early%20stopping%20should%20be%20handled%20by%20the%20user.)

> partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)[source] Perform one epoch of
> stochastic gradient descent on given samples.
>
> Internally, this method uses max_iter = 1. Therefore, it is not
> guaranteed that a minimum of the cost function is reached after
> calling it once. Matters such as objective convergence and early
> stopping should be handled by the user.